# CSS3: Click on round div in the panel

Tags: html, css

I have a panel `div` inside that `div` I have small `round div`. 
When clicking on `panel div` it redirects to another page.

While clicking on small `round div` I get another `div` below it. But when I click on small `round div` then also it redirects to another page. How can I prevent this?

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.small_round_inner_div').click (function (){
      $('.common_cateogory_status_edit_div').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

```css
.panel_div{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background:#dee5e7;
  position:relative;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.small_round_main_div{
  position:absolute;
  right:15px;
  top:15px;
}

.small_round_main_div .small_round_inner_div{
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background:purple;
  border-radius:50%;
}

.common_cateogory_status_edit_div {
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 35px;
  border: thin #ced0d1 solid;
  z-index: 1001;
  width: 130px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  display:none;
}
.common_cateogory_status_edit_div ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.common_cateogory_status_edit_div ul li {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #838383;
}
.common_cateogory_status_edit_div ul li:hover {
  background: #edf1f2;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="https://www.google.com/">

<div class="panel_div">
Some Text
  <div class="small_round_main_div">
    <div class="small_round_inner_div"></div>
    <div class="common_cateogory_status_edit_div fadeIn animated" >
         <ul>
             <li><span>Option 1</span></li>
         </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</a>
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You want to prevent the default behaviour and perhaps also stop the propagation of the event if you use events for the elements up the DOM tree.

- [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)
- [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.small_round_inner_div').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault()
    $('.common_cateogory_status_edit_div').slideToggle('slow');
  });
});
```

```css
.panel_div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #dee5e7;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.small_round_main_div {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 15px;
}

.small_round_main_div .small_round_inner_div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: purple;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.common_cateogory_status_edit_div {
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 35px;
  border: thin #ced0d1 solid;
  z-index: 1001;
  width: 130px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  display: none;
}

.common_cateogory_status_edit_div ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.common_cateogory_status_edit_div ul li {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #838383;
}

.common_cateogory_status_edit_div ul li:hover {
  background: #edf1f2;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="https://www.google.com/">
  <div class="panel_div">
    Some Text
    <div class="small_round_main_div">
      <div class="small_round_inner_div"></div>
      <div class="common_cateogory_status_edit_div fadeIn animated">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <span>Option 1</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: i use angular 2 for that.

Comment: @Rishi What do you mean. Doesn't my answer do what you want?

Comment: actually the scenario is I am developing it in angular 2 . so would it be possible that `event.stropPropagation()` will work for the same?

Comment: @Rishi It's just jQuery, so yes. e.preventDefault() and e.stopPropagation() will work.

Comment: I  can't set angular 2 here so

Answer (score 0):

close each div with an `<a></a>` tag, don't close all with it

Answer (score 0):

just add e.preventDefault(); on click function add (e)

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.small_round_inner_div').click (function (e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.common_cateogory_status_edit_div').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

```css
.panel_div{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background:#dee5e7;
  position:relative;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.small_round_main_div{
  position:absolute;
  right:15px;
  top:15px;
}

.small_round_main_div .small_round_inner_div{
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background:purple;
  border-radius:50%;
}

.common_cateogory_status_edit_div {
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 35px;
  border: thin #ced0d1 solid;
  z-index: 1001;
  width: 130px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  display:none;
}
.common_cateogory_status_edit_div ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.common_cateogory_status_edit_div ul li {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #838383;
}
.common_cateogory_status_edit_div ul li:hover {
  background: #edf1f2;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="https://www.google.com/">

<div class="panel_div">
Some Text
  <div class="small_round_main_div">
    <div class="small_round_inner_div"></div>
    <div class="common_cateogory_status_edit_div fadeIn animated" >
                                          <ul>
                                              <li>
                                                
                                                                                                       <span>Option 1</span>
                                              </li>
                                
                                          </ul>
                                        </div>
  </div>
</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to add **event.stopPropagation()** inside the click function as the following

`innerDiv.click(function(e) {
event.stopPropagation()
}`

for further information please check the docs of **event.stopPropagation()**
https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/